# Display errors on the same page php

Tags: php, html, forms

If someone can figure this out it would be so helpful. So I am trying to display the errors on the same page as my log in form. I believe the problem is the form action as is always loading that page. I have added if empty conditions and variables but not sure how to add them to the HTML.

- The error messages have been added as variables shown in the php code
- Currently, the form action is the problem (I think) its loading checklogin.php with a blank page
- How can I get the error messages displaying below the form on the same page?

Thanks....

HTML:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Entry form login</title>     

</head>

<body>


    <div class= "wrap">
      <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Highdown logo" />
      <h1>Sports day</h1> 
    </div>


    <div class='container'>     
        <div class='form'>
            <form id ="form" action ="checklogin.php" method="post">                                                
                <label for = "user">Username:</label> 
                <input type ="text" name ="username"><br>

                <label for ="password">Password:</label>    
                <input type ="password" name ="password"><br> <span class="error"> <?php echo $error;?></span>  



                <input type ="submit" name ="loginbutton" id ="loginbutton" value ="Log in">    
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>  


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</body>
```

php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once 'db/connect.php';
    $error='';

    if (isset($_POST['loginbutton'])){

        if (empty($_POST['username']) && empty($_POST['password'])) { 
            $error = 'Please enter your username and password';
        }   


        else {
            // Username and password sent from the form
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            // Protect MySQL injection
            $username= stripslashes($username);
            $password = stripslashes($password);
            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);
            $encryptpass = md5($password); // Use md5 to encrypt password 

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE Username = '$username' and Password = '$encryptpass'"; 

            $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);

            // my_sql_num row is counting table row
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            //If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
            if ($count==1) {        
                $_SESSION['Username']=$username;
                header("location:homepage.php");
            }

            else {
                $error = 'Username and/or password is invalid';
            }
        }
    }   
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine them and remove the action attribute from the form element.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once 'db/connect.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Entry form login</title>     
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>


    <div class= "wrap">
      <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Highdown logo" />
      <h1>Sports day</h1> 
    </div>


    <div class='container'>     
        <div class='form'>
            <form id ="form" method="post">                                                
                <label for = "user">Username:</label> 
                <input type ="text" name ="username"><br>

                <label for ="password">Password:</label>    
                <input type ="password" name ="password"><br> <span class="error"> <?php echo $error;?></span>  



                <input type ="submit" name ="loginbutton" id ="loginbutton" value ="Log in">    
            </form>
<?php
    $error='';

    if (isset($_POST['loginbutton'])){

        if (empty($_POST['username']) && empty($_POST['password'])) { 
            $error = 'Please enter your username and password';
        }   


        else {
            // Username and password sent from the form
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            // Protect MySQL injection
            $username= stripslashes($username);
            $password = stripslashes($password);
            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);
            $encryptpass = md5($password); // Use md5 to encrypt password 

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE Username = '$username' and Password = '$encryptpass'"; 

            $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);

            // my_sql_num row is counting table row
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            //If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
            if ($count==1) {        
                $_SESSION['Username']=$username;
                header("location:homepage.php");
            }

            else {
                $error = 'Username and/or password is invalid';
            }
        }
    }   
?>
        </div>
    </div>  


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, I fixed this by removing action and using an 'include'

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to have the form action point to the same script, like so:

```
 action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"
```